# Running tests in parallel mono environment inside of MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mono, monodevelop

I have a parallel mono environment installed to run my app and unit
tests. The app relies on MONO_PATH to find some of the assemblies it
depends on.

Now when I run my unit tests in Monodevelop they don't work because
MONO_PATH gets cleared before running the tests. Setting environment
variables in the project options doesn't help because they don't get set
when running tests.

Any ideas how the tests could be made to work within MD? Are there any
extension points that I could plug in to?

(MD 5.9.8 with Mono 3.12.1; my app requires Mono 3.4)

Answer (score 0):

Make your test project depend on the libraries so they get copied to your `bin/DEBUG|RELEASE/` path before execution?

Take in account that [MONO_PATH is just a debugging tool and shouldn't be used in production](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/best_practices/#monopath).